# RVIZ: Display own pointcloud

Tags: c++, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to build my own point cloud with a gaussian distribution. The visualization with rviz doesn't work.

Here is how I create the pointcloud

```
int sizeOfCloud = 1000;
keypoints.points.resize(sizeOfCloud);
getRandomPointCloud(keypoints, 100, 100, sizeOfCloud);

keypoints.header.frame_id = "base_link";
keypoints.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
keypoints_publisher.publish(keypoints);
```

and here is the function getRandomPointCloud:

```
void getRandomPointCloud(sensor_msgs::PointCloud& pc, int centerX, int centerY, int& sizeOfCloud) {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::normal_distribution<> distX(centerX, 10);
    std::normal_distribution<> distY(centerY, 10);


    for (int i = 0; i < pc.points.size(); i++) {
        double xValue = distX(gen);
        double yValue = distY(gen);
        std::cout << std::round(xValue) << std::endl;
        pc.points[i].x = std::round(xValue);
        pc.points[i].y = std::round(yValue);
    }
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}
```

As I said, it can't be displayed in rviz. I do select by topic, select the proper topic and then there is nothing on the screen. Topic is correct and if I set the grid to base_link then everything with the topic is okay. Maybe I have to set a special attribute in rviz or I don't build my pointcloud correctly.

Edit:
My Publisher:

```
ros::Publisher keypoints_publisher;
keypoints_publisher = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud>("/keypoints", 1000);
```

Edit2:

Here is a screenshot of rviz. Maybe this shows my problem better

[image: Screenshot RVIZ]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242297/rviz:-display-own-pointcloud/) by [JanB](https://answers.ros.org/users/25957/janb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-08-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) on 2016-08-24**:
How is your `keypoints_publisher` defined?

**Comment by [JanB](https://answers.ros.org/users/25957/janb/) on 2016-08-24**:
I've edited it in my question. Sorry for forgetting this piece of code.

**Comment by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) on 2016-08-25**:
What is your fixed frame, the first line of `Displays` window.

**Comment by [JanB](https://answers.ros.org/users/25957/janb/) on 2016-08-25**:
I've writen base_link in Fixed Frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Do `rostopic echo /keypoints` and see if the messages are right.
2. Add a `PointCloud` in RViz, select that `/keypoints` topic, see if the `status` is OK.
3. Choose `base_link` as the fixed frame, see if everything is all right. If you want `odom` or `map` to be the fixed frame, you need to make sure your tf `odom->base_link` or `map->odom->base_link` is provided.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) on 2016-08-24**:
These debugging steps are a great place to start. Without seeing the whole program it's hard to know, but perhaps you're publishing a single point cloud immediately after calling advertise() ? Since the peer-to-peer connections take time to set up, it's recommended to (re)publish topics periodically

**Comment by [JanB](https://answers.ros.org/users/25957/janb/) on 2016-08-25**:
Thank you, step 1 and 2 is already done and successful. Step 3 is a little bit confusing to me. I don't know how to solve this base_link fixed frame. I edited my initial post to show a screen shot from my rviz.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-08-25**:
@Morgan has a good point, are you just publishing the cloud once? If so, you should try publishing it periodically, like once every second until you get things working.

**Comment by [JanB](https://answers.ros.org/users/25957/janb/) on 2016-08-25**:
thank you. I do publish it for a static period. And the published cloud can be seen with "rostopic echo /keypoints"